# golang - Content of a pointer in a slice changes during recursive function run

Tags: go

```
func getAllCertainDivs(className string, idName string, htmlTag *HtmlTag, matchingDivs *[]*HtmlTag) {
    fmt.Println(htmlTag.Class)
    if htmlTag.XMLName.Local == "div" {
        if htmlTag.Class == className && htmlTag.Id == idName {
            *matchingDivs = append(*matchingDivs, htmlTag)
        }
    }

    for _, tag := range htmlTag.ChildTags {
        getAllCertainDivs(className, idName, &tag, matchingDivs)
    }
}
```

In the function above, as you can see, I pass a pointer of a slice into the `getAllCertainDivs` function. At a point a `HtmlTag` pointer is pushed into the slice `matchingDivs`. After the `append` I check the content of the matchingDiv slice, before letting the function call itself recursively again. Then below the if where `append` was made, the function calls itself recursively one time. And I stop at the `fmt.Println(htmlTag.Class)` and check the content of `matchingDivs` slice again. And the content is completely different than before.

There has only been one `append`, how can the content change ? Does `golang` use the same `HtmlTag` pointer, everytime I pass it into next recursive call ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tag` variable is declared once at the start of the loop, and the value of `tag` is overwritten on each iteration. This is the same problem you see in the [FAQ](https://golang.org/doc/faq) with: ["What happens with closures running as goroutines?"](https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines)

You can declare a new variable during each iteration to get a unique pointer for the function call:

```
for _, tag := range htmlTag.ChildTags {
    tag := tag
    getAllCertainDivs(className, idName, &tag, matchingDivs)
}
```

Alternatively you can elide the range value, and use the index directly:

```
for i := range htmlTag.ChildTags {
    getAllCertainDivs(className, idName, &htmlTag.ChildTags[i], matchingDivs)
}
```

Comment: You mean, tag is created at an address once, and the value in the address is overwritten in each loop?

Comment: @OzumSafa: yes, precisely.